# Рисовать на сайте

Tags: javascript, html

интересует такая вещь, как рисование на сайте. Как пример "электронная подпись" ты там водишь мышкой и рисуешь. Я пытался гуглить, но без успешно. Помогите пожалуйста, если можно используя только HTML + JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использую только JS

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

document.body.style.margin = 0;
canvas.style.position = 'fixed';


const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
resize();

const pos = { x: 0, y: 0 };

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', setPosition);
document.addEventListener('mouseenter', setPosition);

function setPosition(e) {
  pos.x = e.clientX;
  pos.y = e.clientY;
}

function resize() {
  ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

function draw(e) {
  if (e.buttons !== 1) return;

  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#c0392b';

  ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y); 
  setPosition(e);
  ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);

  ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: У меня почему-то, пишет не под курсором, а правее. добавил в код лишь <canvas id="smile" width="200" height="200">